# Why does jQuery Validate plugin do validation without calling validate()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have just give option to the validate (errorElement, ...), and I set the rules, without calling validate method, or associating it with any event, but jQuery validates automatically, how to control when it validates?

Comment: Please provide code example

Comment: And how have you set your jQuery, and validation, up? Without seeing your code this question cannot be answered in any reasonable form.

Comment: $('form').validate({errorelement:'span'});
$('input').rules('add',{min:0});

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going to need to provide a lot more detail about what you're trying to do, but I can answer your question as you've written it so far.

> **Title**:  why does jquery validate without calling validate?

[`.validate()` is called *once* to initialize the plugin on the form](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options).  It is not a method for triggering validation on demand.  Once initialized, the form will automatically validate as per the various event callbacks built into the plugin.  More details follow...

> **OP**:  i have just give option to the validate (errorElement, ...), and i set
>   the rules, without calling validate method, or associating it with any
>   event, but jquery validates automatically, how to control when it
>   validates ?

You do not need to associate the plugin with any events because the plugin already does this automatically.  It would be pretty useless if it didn't.

[When you call `.validate()`, you are initializing the plugin on the form](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options).  So, yes, this means the form is now ready and it will automatically do a validation test triggered on all common events such as `submit`, `onkeyup`, `onfocusout`, and select, button & checkbox `click`.  Why would you not want that?

To perform a validation test programmatically, you can call [the built-in `.valid()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) which is very much like the `submit` event in that it will trigger the validation test on the *entire form* and the form will display any errors.  `.valid()` will also return a boolean `true` or `false` indicating if the form passes the validation test.

If you need to trigger a validation test only on a single element, rather than the entire form, you would use `$('#myelement').valid()`.  Again, any message is displayed and a boolean value returned.

If for whatever reason you need to actually "disable" and "enable" validation completely, you can not directly do this, as there is no built-in method for un-binding the plugin from the form.  However, you can simulate it by using [the built-in `rules('remove')` and `rules('add')` methods](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules).  Without any rules on any fields, it will simply behave as if there's no validation at all.  However, you would still be able to use other plugin options like the [`submitHandler` callback](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), just in case you are using ajax to do the data submission.

Comment: thank you, so i don't recommend the ebook untitled "pro jquery", it teaches this the wrong way

Comment: @YounesCh, you're welcome.  Perhaps you can edit your OP to explain more about what this book tried to teach you.

Comment: it says that we have to call validate once for the configuration and another time for the validation