# jquery validate onchange

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, onchange

I'm using http://jqueryvalidation.org/ plugin.

It validate on key up but no on change. 
For example:

```
<input type="text" id="test1" value="" name="test1">
<input type="checkbox" id="test2" name="test2" value="1"> 

jQuery('#test2').change(function() {
jQuery('#test1').val('Test1'); });
```

if I'm validating, validate error at #test1 shows, but when i click checkbox, it's not hidding.

I can do it in this way:

```
jQuery('#test2').change(function() {
jQuery('#test1').val('Test1');
jQuery('#test1').valid(); });
```

it works, but how to implement onchange method in validation plugin, for automatic, every field onchange validation? Not only onkeyup, but also onchange?

Comment: 'onchange: true' will be very good, but it wasn't implemented in this plugin. 
So, maybe someone has made this or has idea, how to implement this method?

Comment: Where is the `.validate()` code?  Where are the validation rules?  What are you really trying to do here?  Why would an error message disappear on the click of a checkbox?  Do you want the rule for `test1` to _depend_ on the checked state of `test2`?  If so, then explain this in enough detail so that we can help you achieve it.

Comment: No, the plugin does not have an `onchange` option.  However, it's not needed since it captures any "change" via `onkeyup` for text fields, `onfocusout` for all fields, and `onclick` for radio and checkbox fields.

Comment: `onkeyup`+`onfocusout`+`onclick` ≠ `onchange`. `onchange` actually checks if the value has been changed and does not fire on every click, focusout and keypress. It also catches pasting through right-click menu etc. The plugin definately needs and lacks it.

Answer (score 1):

Start using 'input' event instead of 'change'.

```
jQuery('#test2').on('input', function() {
    // do your stuff 
});
```

Comment: it's Awesome, Thx

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
jQuery('#test2').on('click',function() {
    $(this).validate({
       // your code here
    });
});
```

Read [jQuery Validator -- only validate onblur event (not onchange)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592857/jquery-validator-only-validate-onblur-event-not-onchange)

Comment: Yes, my exampla works in the same way. 
But i wan't declare this for every field. I need do it automatic with this plugin.

Comment: `.validate()` is the method to _INITIALIZE_ the plugin.  It is **not** the method for "testing" validity of the form.  See `.valid()` method.  Read this for edification:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14858168/594235